# Which type do I have to use for this ltree query?

Tags: postgresql, types

I have a LTREE Field, called `house_path`, this query works for me:

```
WHERE house_path ~ '*.35.*';
```

However this query doesn't work for me:

```
WHERE house_path ~ '*.35.*'::text;

-> operator does not exist: ltree ~ text
```

Which type has the second argument to have? So that it works?
I'm asking because I would like to write a function where I can pass the second argument as variable. And I don't know what type the second variable should be.

Answer (score 1):

Use lquery type.

```
WHERE house_path ~ '*.35.*'::lquery;
```